# JPQL : Named Parameters not detected

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql, openjpa

I'm trying to make a **very** simple search motor for my database. Basically it selects elements which either name or description contains at least one of the search words. Here is the method :

```
    public List<Product> getProductSearch(List<String> tokens) {
    em.clear();
    String query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE ";
    TypedQuery<Product> queryExec;
    List<Product> result;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
        query += "p.nom LIKE :token" + i + " OR p.description LIKE :token" + i; //invoke a parameter named token<i> for the i-th token
        if(i != tokens.size()-1) query += " OR ";
    }
    System.out.println("Query : " + query);
    queryExec = em.createQuery(query, Product.class);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
        queryExec.setParameter("token"+i,"%" + tokens.get(i) + "%"); //Declare every used parameters
    }
    
    result = queryExec.getResultList();
    
    return result;
}
```

However, when I test this method with a simple search query (e.g "word1 word2"), JPA acts like I didn't declare the parameters, and also modifies the query. When the final query generated by my method is :

```
SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.nom LIKE :token0 OR p.description LIKE :token0 OR p.nom LIKE :token1 OR p.description LIKE :token1
```

With `token0` and `token1` being declared equal to `word1` and `word2`, the JPA log says that the actual executed query is :

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.categorie, t0.description, t0.nom, t0.prix, t0.score, t0.stock FROM produits t0 WHERE (t0.nom LIKE ? ESCAPE '\\' OR t0.description LIKE ? ESCAPE '\\' OR t0.nom LIKE ? ESCAPE '\\' OR t0.description LIKE ? ESCAPE '\\') [params=?, ?, ?, ?]
```

So my questions are :

-Is this behavior normal?

-Where is my error?

-What would be the best way to fix it?

I'm using eclipse, OpenJPA, MySQL, and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this behavior is normal.

In a log, you see a SQL query, not a JPQL query. This SQL query is usually executed via a JDBC `PreparedStatement` and **named parameters** are translated to **positional parameters** - it's an internal working of a JPA provider.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was not making any errors, I made some research about it and now I understand better the internal working of JPA/JPQL.